# ¿Por qué me devuelve el tipo de dato cuando intento crear un objeto con los valores de un array, en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

No sé qué estoy haciendo mal; intento crear un objeto con propiedades cuyos valores los debo sacar de dos arrays. Estos son los arrays:

```
const saboresHelados= ["manzana","fresa","maracuya","mango","chicle","banano","vainilla","coco","chocolate"]
const precios= [3000,2000,1500,1000,500,3200,3500,6000,4000]
```

Y este es el código:

```
const precios2= precios.map((precio) => precio)//consigo cada precio del array
            console.log("Aqui", precios2)//Acá imprimo para saber que si estoy guardando los precios en la variable
            const saborConPrecio= saboresHelados.map(sabor => {
                return {
                    sabor: sabor,
                    precio: precios2
                }
            })
            menuDelDia.push(saborConPrecio)
```

Intento guardar los objetos en un array vacío llamado "menuDelDia" y me los guarda pero el problema es este: no entiendo por qué en el valor de los precios me sale el tipo [array] y no los valores como tal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `precios2` es un Array. Tu error es pensar que estás tomando un elemento del Array cuando en realidad estás tomando todo el Array.

Comment: Es cierto la función map de por si sola devuelve un array. Estuve obviando que map recibe en sus parámetros también el índice del array y eso me puede ayudar a solucionar. Gracias brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi personalmente me parece un enredo usar 2 funciones `map` para eso, porque no usas un `for` y ya? o un único `map`?

con un `for`:

```js
const saboresHelados=["manzana","fresa","maracuya","mango","chicle","banano","vainilla","coco","chocolate"];
const precios= [3000,2000,1500,1000,500,3200,3500,6000,4000];

let menu = [];
for(let i=0; i<saboresHelados.length; i++){
   menu.push({ 
      sabor: saboresHelados[i],
      precio: precios[i]
   });
}

console.log(menu)
```

O tambien mas sencillo con un solo `map`:

```js
const saboresHelados=["manzana","fresa","maracuya","mango","chicle","banano","vainilla","coco","chocolate"];
const precios= [3000,2000,1500,1000,500,3200,3500,6000,4000];

const menu = saboresHelados.map((sabor, i) => ({
   sabor: sabor,
   precio: precios[i]
}));

console.log(menu);
```

Esto funcionaría, si estamos seguros que siempre `saboresHelado` y `precios` tienen la misma cantidad de elementos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho la solución, la verdad es que estaba obviando que la función map como parámetro recibe el índice del arreglo y pude haberlo utilizado para solucionarlo. Gracias!. Arreglare el tema de los dos map que no son necesarios. Tus soluciones me ayudaron pana, gracias

Answer (score 1):

@Hugo como dice Mauricio el problema que tienes es que le estas asignando el array entero al precio en vez de decirle que precio es. Te pongo un ejemplo si es esto lo que estas buscando.

```js
const saboresHelados=["manzana","fresa","maracuya","mango","chicle","banano","vainilla","coco","chocolate"];
const precios= [3000,2000,1500,1000,500,3200,3500,6000,4000];
var menuDelDia = new Array();
const precios2= precios.map((precio) => precio)//consigo cada precio del array
            console.log("Aqui", precios2)//Acá imprimo para saber que si estoy guardando los precios en la variable
            const saborConPrecio= saboresHelados.map(function(x, index){
                return {
                    sabor: x,
                    precio: precios[index]
                }
            })
            menuDelDia.push(saborConPrecio);
            console.log(menuDelDia)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió mucho la solución, la verdad es que estaba obviando que la función map como parámetro recibe el índice del arreglo y pude haberlo utilizado para solucionarlo. Gracias!